# SQL Conceptual Order Evaluation

Tags: sql, select

Can someone explain, what is conceptual order of execution of a SELECT statement and provide an example of one please?

I've searched on Google but they all seem to use the same example without thorough explanation.

Comment: Could you provide some context for this question?

Comment: In context of Oracle, you can get an understanding from here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15586_01/server.1111/e25789/sqllangu.htm#CHDFCAGA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `select` query is evaluated, conceptually, in the following order:

1. The `from` clause
2. The `where` clause
3. The `group by` clause
4. The `having` clause
5. The `select` clause
6. The `order by` clause

This is "conceptual" processing and explains some of the scoping rules of SQL.  The way queries are executed in practice may differ.

SQL Server documentation explains this ordering [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement).

Comment: Where is the JOIN?