# Using alias in the WHERE and HAVING statements?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, having-clause

Example:

```
SELECT customer_id, address_id as addressID 
FROM customer 
WHERE addressID = 5
```

But, using the HAVING clause works perfectly fine. So why aliases don't work in the where clause?

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: Because that is how the SQL language is defined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only MySQL permits alises in `HAVING`, it is not standard SQL (see here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50391/why-does-mysql-allow-having-to-use-select-aliases ) please note that no other major RDBMS allows the use of aliases in `WHERE` or `HAVING`.

The reason you can't use aliases in `WHERE` (and `HAVING`) is because `SELECT` is actually evaluated after most other sub-clauses: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21693272/159145

> A `SELECT` query is evaluated, conceptually, in the following order:
>
> 1. The `FROM` clause
> 2. The `WHERE` clause
> 3. The `GROUP BY` clause
> 4. The `HAVING` clause
> 5. The `SELECT` clause
> 6. The `ORDER BY` clause

So your query:

```
SELECT
    customer_id,
    address_id AS addressID 
FROM
    customer 
WHERE
    addressID = 5
```

Is evaluated in this order:

```
1: FROM
    customer
2: WHERE
    address_id = 5
3: SELECT
    customer_id,
    address_id AS addressID
```

As you cans see, if the `WHERE` part referenced `addressID` instead of `address_id` the query execution engine would complain because `addressID` is not defined at that point.

MySQL does permit the referencing of (normal) aliases in `HAVING` by doing a (non-standard) neat trick where it partially evaluates the `SELECT` *before* it evaluates `HAVING` - and because MySQL has a handling of aliases that means the evaluation engine can be sure that the alias is valid (which is why most other RDBMS engines don't allow the use of aliases in `HAVING` when they otherwise should be able to). But you can't use an alias in `WHERE` because if there's a `GROUP BY` then it might render an alias meaningless, consider:

```
SELECT
    SUM( foo ) AS baz,
    created
FROM
    foo
WHERE
    baz > 5 -- Meaningless: the GROUP BY hasn't been evaluated yet, so `baz` is unavailable
GROUP BY
    created
```

MySQL explains this in their manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a `WHERE` clause. This restriction is imposed because when the `WHERE` clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.
>
> The `WHERE` clause determines which rows should be included in the `GROUP BY` clause, but it refers to the alias of a column value that is not known until after the rows have been selected, and grouped by the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: That is just an exceptionally thorough answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your descriptive answer!