# Write a query to determine how many product have been sold with profit

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am very new to SQL. I have three tables, transactions, products, and  customers. I want to know how many products have been sold with profit.

```
SELECT t.product_id, p.id,  sum(t.total_price / t.quantity) - p.price As profit 
From transactions as t , products As p
INNER JOIN transactions
on t.product_id = p.id
GROUP by t.product_id
```

I have only a total price column in my transactions table. Should I divide total_price to quantity or * ? How about my all query?

Comment: This query looks fine to me, at a glance, except you don't need list transactions both in `from` and `join`. Choose one. If you want only profitable products, maybe add `having profit > 0`.

Comment: Thanks in advance. Should I add having profit > 0 after Group BY?

Comment: yes, after group by

Comment: What about select Count?
Can it help me to know how many product have been sold with profit?

Comment: To get just the count, I'd use this query as a subquery. `select count(*) from (<this query from the post>)`)

Comment: Dear Sergio, a lot of thanks. it  is solved

Comment: Hm, mysql should be able to use aliases in having (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49888360/using-alias-in-the-where-and-having-statements). But no worries, just inline the calculation, `having (sum(t.total_price / t.quantity) - p.price) > 0`

Comment: Many thanks.
How Can I calculate the total amount of profits with these tables?

Comment: If you have the subquery working, it's trivial. I'll leave this as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.product_id,sum(t.total_price / t.quantity - p.price) as profit
  FROM transactions as t
     INNER JOIN product as p on t.id = p.id
       GROUP by t.product_id
         order by t.product_id
```

Can you try this way

Comment: The indentation here is a bit strange.

Comment: Should I use select count?
I would like to how many products sold with profit