# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Collect_Date' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am struggling with trying to apply a date filter to my query. I keep getting this error message

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Collect_Date' to
>   data type int

Here is my code:

```
SELECT
    Location_ID, 
    CONVERT(Date,CONVERT(varchar(10),Collect_Month_Key,101)) as 'Collect_Date', 
    Calc_Gross_Totals, Loc_Country, 
    CONVERT(varchar(8),Collect_Month_Key)+'-'+Location_ID as 'Unique Key'
FROM 
    FT_GPM_NPM_CYCLES, 
    LU_Location, 
    LU_Loc_Country
WHERE
    LU_Location.LU_Loc_Country_Key=LU_Loc_Country.LU_Loc_Country_Key
    AND FT_GPM_NPM_CYCLES.Lu_Loc_Key= LU_Location.LU_Loc_Key
    AND Collect_Month_Key<>-1 
    AND 'Collect_Date'>=2016-1-1
ORDER BY
    Location_ID, 
    Collect_Date;
```

If someone could help that would be appreciated. I am also getting a different error when I try to do the `Month(Collect_Date)`. So if anyone knows why on that I would appreciate it. I have attched a picture with the code nd results I am getting.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: `'Collect_Date'>=2016-1-1`? That's the same as `'Collect_Date'>=2014` *How* can the **literal string** `'Collect Date'` have a greater value than the **integer** `2014`? I suspect you mean `Collect_Date >= '20160101'`.

Comment: And, to expand on Gordan's point: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: Good to know for the join I will adjust that. Thanks for the link. I am trying to make it so the collect date is greater than or equal to 2016. I tried using that and it wasn't putting the filter in, it was showing all dates. I think there is a problem with my date conversion.

Comment: `'Collect_Date'>=2016-1-1` neither side of that expression is a date, @kevinh. The left side is a **literal string** (a `varchar`), where as the other is 3 `int` values which evaluate to `2014`. If you want rows that occur on or after 1st Jan 2016 then the expression I gave above is what you are after.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for the clarification. I was able to get it to work by doing that. Except I had to use `Collect_Month_Key >= '20160101'` and I couldn't use the `collect_date` that i created. Which I am not sure why. I think this is why I am having problems with getting the month number out of the `collect_date`. I am also using 101 as the style in my convert formula ans it is coming out as ANSI.

Comment: I think the problem that you're having with CollectDate is simply that you're using it in the WHERE clause which gets evaluated before the SELECT clause, where it's defined. it simply doesn't exist at the time the WHERE clause is evaluated. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693208/sql-conceptual-order-evaluation

Comment: So if I don't put the `collect_Date` in the WHERE, where should I put it for something like this in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I see whats going on, you are trying to use the alias in the select statement. You can't do that, There are a few other issues that have been covered in the comments, but here is the immediate answer to the question:

```
Select  Location_ID 
  , Convert(Date,CONVERT(varchar(10),Collect_Month_Key,101)) as Collect_Date 
  , Calc_Gross_Totals
  , Loc_Country 
  , CONVERT(varchar(8),Collect_Month_Key)+'-'+Location_ID as [Unique Key]
From FT_GPM_NPM_CYCLES
  , LU_Location
  , LU_Loc_Country
Where LU_Location.LU_Loc_Country_Key=LU_Loc_Country.LU_Loc_Country_Key
  and FT_GPM_NPM_CYCLES.Lu_Loc_Key= LU_Location.LU_Loc_Key
  and Collect_Month_Key <> -1 
  and Convert(Date,CONVERT(varchar(10),Collect_Month_Key,101)) >= '2016-1-1'
Order By Location_ID, Collect_Date;
```

Comment: Aww, gotcha. I see what you did. I already made the adjustment for the joins that was suggested early on. I am now doing left join instead of the "," on the `FROM` statement. So my last problem is when I add this to the select statement `MONTH('Collect_Date')` to try and get the collect month I get this error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string". Do I need to convert `Collect_Date` Back to an int before I can do `MONTH`?

Comment: I figured it out. I did this: `MONTH(Convert(Date,CONVERT(varchar(10),Collect_Month_Key,101))) as MONTH`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated query that brings following modifications:

- As commented by Robert Sheahan, you cannot  use a resultset column alias in the `WHERE` clause
- As commented by Larnu, since you are storing dates as strings, you could simply do *string comparaison* to filter records (and return string values). With this technique, you do not need additional condition `Collect_Month_Key <> -1`, since string `'-1`' is not greater than string `'20160101'`.
- use explicit joins instead of implicit joins (comment by Gordon Linoff)
- I added table aliases : they make the query easier to read (and make it possible to self-join a table...)
- I would also recommend to to prefix *all* columns being used in the query with their table alias. This clearly indicates from which table each column comes from, and makes the query easier to understand and maintain. NB: if `Collect_Month_Key` belongs to a table other than `FT_GPM_NPM_CYCLES`, you want to move the condition from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the relevant `JOIN`)

Query:

```
SELECT
    Location_ID, 
    Collect_Month_Key AS Collect_Date, 
    Calc_Gross_Totals, 
    Loc_Country, 
    CONVERT(varchar(8),Collect_Month_Key) + '-' + Location_ID AS Unique_Key
FROM 
    FT_GPM_NPM_CYCLES AS cyc
    INNER JOIN LU_Location AS loc
        ON cyc.Lu_Loc_Key = loc.LU_Loc_Key
    INNER JOIN LU_Loc_Country AS cty
        ON loc.LU_Loc_Country_Key = cty.LU_Loc_Country_Key
WHERE 
    Collect_Month_Key > '20160101'
ORDER BY 
    Location_ID, 
    Collect_Month_Key
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a good summary of everything and much less complicated. I appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome @kevinh!

Comment: Perhaps I'm being pedantic about dates (maybe it's my unforgiving Oracle background). If `Collect_Month_Key` is a date, then I recommend explicitly converting the hard-coded value `'20160101'` to a date as well before using it in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your comment "So if I don't put the collect_Date in the WHERE, where should I put it for something like this in the future?", I suggest Common Table Expressions. Functionally they are equivalent to defining a derived table in the FROM clause, but they move it "above" so it feels more like "before" and I think they make it much easier to read. To convert GMB's excellent solution to using a CTE:

```
--Leading ; because CTEs require prvious command terminated explicitly
;WITH cteWithDates as ( --cteDates becomes a virtual temporary table
    SELECT
        cyc.* --Keep all the original columns of FT_GPM_NPM_CYCLES
        , Collect_Month_Key AS Collect_Date --and add Collect_Date and Unique_Key
        , CONVERT(varchar(8),Collect_Month_Key) + '-' + Location_ID AS Unique_Key
    FROM FT_GPM_NPM_CYCLES AS cyc
) --you could add more CTEs with the following format, 
--all become available at the end
--, cteMore as (SELECT ... FROM ...)
--the first line after the closing ) has access to all CTEs, but ONLY that line
SELECT Location_ID, 
    Collect_Date, 
    Calc_Gross_Totals, 
    Loc_Country, 
    Unique_Key
FROM 
    cteWithDates AS cyc --Use the CTE as you would your original table, 
    --but the added fields are now available EVERYWHERE in your query!
        INNER JOIN LU_Location AS loc
            ON cyc.Lu_Loc_Key = loc.LU_Loc_Key
        INNER JOIN LU_Loc_Country AS cty
            ON loc.LU_Loc_Country_Key = cty.LU_Loc_Country_Key
WHERE 
    Collect_Date > '20160101' --NOW you can use CollectDate!
ORDER BY 
    Location_ID, 
    Collect_Date --And here too
```

Note that this is much more efficient than defining an actual temporary table with #TableName, because the query optimizer can drop unused records from the CTE but it has to put them all into the #temporary table, a huge performance difference if your table is large and the matching subset small.