# MySQL performance - cross join vs left join

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

I am wondering how MySQL (or its underlying engine) processes the queries.
There are two set queries below (one uses left join and the other one uses cross join), which eventually will give the same result.

My question is, how come the processing time of the two sets of queries are similar?

What I expected is that the first set query will run quicker because the computer is dealing with  left join so the size of the "table" won't be expanding, while the second set of queries makes the size of the "table" (what I assume is that the computer needs to get the result of the cross-join from multiple tables before it can go ahead and do the where clause) relatively larger.

```
select s.*, a.score as score_01, b.score as score_02
from student s
left join (select \* from sc where cid = '01') a using (sid)
left join (select \* from sc where cid = '02') b using (sid)
where a.score > b.score;
```

```
select s.*, a.score as score_01, b.score as score_02
from student s
,(select * from sc where cid = '01') a
,(select * from sc where cid = '02') b
where a.score > b.score and a.sid = b.sid and s.sid = a.sid;
```

I tried both sets of queries and expected the processing time for the first set query will be shorter, but it is not the case.

Comment: "...the first set query will run quicker because the computer is dealing with left join so the size of the "table" won't be expanding..." -- how so? A left join is a join, so it will produce multiple rows for each row in the left table.

Comment: The first query is malformed. The left joins are silently converted to inner joins by the engine because of the predicate `where a.score > b.score`. Please fix the query.

Comment: I have revised the question accordingly.
So "where a.score > b.score" is actually the reason why the two queries... how could you tell if this predicate makes the whole thing become inner joins though?

Comment: Technically, the second one is an `INNER JOIN` since you have specified the relationships in the `WHERE` clause instead of `ON` or `USING`.

Comment: And the first query _may_ be an `INNER JOIN`, too -- since you have constraints (other than NULL test) on the tables.

Comment: All SQL is compiled into execution plans. In MySQL look in to EXPLAIN if you're interested in the plan a query is compiled in to.

Comment: To understand why a WHERE clause can effectively turn an OUTER JOIN in to an INNER JOIN, take note of the order in which a query is evaluated; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693208/sql-conceptual-order-evaluation

Comment: Make your life simpler by NEVER using `,` for joins. There is (+) style syntax to make outer joins work, but it's messy and harder to read or debug, sometimes is itself bugged and, most importantly, the join syntax (ANSI-92) superceded it Thirty Years Ago

Comment: Finally, as well as being compiled, SQL is a declarative language, you're treating it as an imperative language.  If you're interested, just research the terms, if not interested; SQL compilers are clever and can use black magic to determine what your expression Means, and so optimise the solution to it.

Comment: The link you shared @MatBailie mentioned that "select" is executed after "where", so it means the complier will use black magic to restrict the "select" action processing to the "limited table (where condition meets). But since "from" is before "where", doesn't it mean that the outer join is performed before checking the "where" condition?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693208/sql-conceptual-order-evaluation

Comment: I am also told not to use the implicit way (using `,`) to use outer join, instead i should use  `full outer join`. However, don't you find using `,` makes the code more readable?

Comment: I just looked up the terms, I think you have already made the explanation pretty layman.
`imperative code focuses on writing an explicit sequence of commands to describe how you want the computer to do things, and declarative code focuses on specifying the result of what you want`

Comment: The outer join is not PERFORMED before the WHERE, the expression is evaluated first, has precedence over, logically precedes...during the parsing and compilation to an execution plan. No data (other than statistics to inform the cost based estimates) is read until the whole plan is compiled and starts executing. But, logically, that means you have `WHERE a > b` in a place where either value can be NULL due to the outer joins. But boolean expressions involving NULL don't evaluate to TRUE and so those outer results are ALWAYS  Explicitly filtered out. And the optimiser know that.

Comment: Never ever ever ever ever ever use comma notation for joins. Join syntax wasn't invented for a laugh. Joins are easier to read as the join predicate MUST be present near the join, not hidden in a where clause that may have conditions unrelated to joins and may even be missing predicates for some joins. Do Not Use Them. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: @MatBailie, etc, -- I added (in my Answer) a long discussion elaborating on many of your Comments.  And addressing a few semi-misconceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to `sc`:

```
INDEX(sid, cid, score)
```

Better yet, if you have a useless `id` on `side` replace it with

```
PRIMARY KEY(sid, cid)`
```

(Assuming that pair is Unique.)

With either of those fixes, I expect both of your queries run at similar speed, and faster than currently.

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

**Addressing some of the Comments**

MySQL ignores the keywords `INNER`, `OUTER`, and `CROSS`.  So, it up to the `WHERE` to figure whether it is "inner" or "outer".

MySQL throws the `ON` and `WHERE` conditions together (except when it matters for `LEFT`), then decides what is used for filtering (`WHERE`) so it *may* be able to do that first.  Then other conditions (which belonged in `ON`) help it get to the 'next' table.

So...  Please use `ON` to say how the tables are related; use `WHERE` for filtering.  (And don't use the old comma-join.)

That is, MySQL will [usually] look at one table at a time, doing a "Nested Loop Join" (NLJ) to get to the next.

There are many possible ways to evaluate a `JOIN`; MySQL ponders which one might be best, then uses that.

The order of non-LEFT `JOINs` does not matter, nor does the order of expressions `AND'd` together in `WHERE`.

In some situations, a `HAVING` expression can (and is) moved to the `WHERE` clause.

Although `FROM` comes before `WHERE`, the two get somewhat tangled up together.  But, in general, the clauses are required to be in a certain order, and that order is *logically* the order that things have to happen in.

It is up to the Optimizer to combine steps.  For example

```
WHERE a = 1
ORDER BY b
```

*and* the table has `INDEX(a,b)` -- The index will be used to do both, essentially at the same time.  Ditto for

```
SELECT a, MAX(b)
    ...
    GROUP BY a
    ORDER BY a
```

can hop through the BTree index on (a,b) *and* deliver the results without an extra sort pass for either the `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY`.

`SELECT x` is executed after `WHERE y = 'abc'` -- Well, in some sense it is.  But if you have `INDEX(y,x)`, the Optimizer is smart enough to grab the `x` values while it is performing the `WHERE`.

When a `WHERE` references more than one table of a `JOIN`, the Optimizer has a quandary.  Which table should it start its NLJ with?  It has some statistics to help make the decision, but it does not always get it right.  It will *usually*

1. filter on one of the tables
2. NLJ to get to the next table, meanwhile throwing in any `WHERE` clauses for that table in with the `ON` clause.
3. Repeat for other tables.

When there is both a `WHERE` and an `ORDER BY`, the Optimizer will usually filter filter, then sort.  But sometimes (not always correctly) it will decide to use an index for the `ORDER BY` (thereby eliminating the sort) and filter as it reads the table.  `LIMIT`, which is logically done last further muddies the decision.

MySQL does not have `FULL OUTER JOIN`.  It can be simulated with two `JOIN` and a `UNION`.  (It is only very rarely needed.)